# Notify user of new comments by email

Tags: php, mysql

I have a blog and I want to add a function "Notify me of new comments by email" to each post, when the user comments a post.

Im working with PHP and MySQL.

I was thinking about to send a mail to the users who has commented some posts and has checked the checkbox "Notify me of new comments by email" with a query like:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(post_id) AS NumberOfComments FROM comments WHERE post_id = $post_id");

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

if($row['NumberOfComments '] > $NumberOfComments){
    mail("someone@example.com","subject","message");
}
```

But if someone deleted a comment from the post and a new comment has been added then it would be the same number of comments and no mail will be sent. Any ideas on how the query could be better?

Answer (score 1):

Do this mailing on the insertion from the comment to the database, then you dont need this extra query.

EDIT:
So you store the user's who want to get notified in the database
with a table with a `id` `user_id` `post_id` i named it `comment_notify`
then you can do something like that

```
// Insert comment to database
$userWhoWantGetNotified = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comment_notify WHERE post_id = $postId");
while ($entry = mysql_fetch_assoc($userWhoWantGetNotified )) {
    $userId = $entry["user_id"];
    // get email from user_id
    mail(..);
}
```

Comment: Could use more context, so beginners are informed correctly :)

Comment: How could the query look like and how could I send the mail to a specific person who has checked the checkbox  "Notify me of new comments by email"?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on when you want to notify the user.

Do they want to be notified of every comment?  Then the functionality which posts the comment would also send the notification.  Any time a comment is posted, check for users to be notified and notify them.

Do they want a periodic (daily, weekly, etc.) notification that there exist new comments?  Then you still don't want a count.  What you want in that case is to check if there exist new records.  There are a couple of ways to go about this:

1. Based on identifiers.  If you know the ID of the last comment about which the user was notified (which you may need to store somewhere in a notifications table) then you check if there exist new IDs above that one.  If so, there are new comments.
2. Based on date.  If you know the timestamp of the last comment about which the user was notified (which you can store somewhere or calculate on the fly based on the period of notifications) then you check if there exist new comments since that time.  If so, there are new comments.

As you've found, simply *counting* the records isn't a meaningful indication of what you're looking for.  All a record count does is tell you how many records there are.  If you want to know *when* those records were posted, you need a timestamp of some kind.  If you want to know if records match previously known records, you need an identifier of some kind.

Never assume information derived from data which doesn't hold that information.  Store the information you need to know.

Comment: I just want a simple way to notify the user when new comments/comment is added - with only ONE notification no matter how many comments has been added

Comment: Im still a beginner. How could I get the last comment id and How could a query look like if I knew the last id of the comment in the post?

Comment: @user3740970: So, a periodic notification then?  That's exactly what I describe in this answer.  Simply record what the user was last notified of (either timestamp or identifier) and then check if there have been new rows added since then.  If so, then there are new records.  For example, if the user was last notified of Comment ID 245 and the max Comment ID is now 257 then there are new comments.

Comment: @user3740970: `SELECT MAX(id) FROM Comments`